# Refresh custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to find the min value of colored cells within a google sheet. After receiving some help from this forum, I am able to get what I need. But the results don't seem to dynamic based on the change in min value of change in color of the cell. Can someone please help out?

```
/**
* @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
* @param {range} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/

function minValColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
var values = range.getValues();

var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
var color = colorCell.getBackground();

var colourarray=[]

for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++){
     for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++){
        if( bg[i][j] == color ){
           colourarray.push(values[i][j])                   
        }
     }
}

   var smallest = colourarray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the min is "+smallest[0])
   return smallest[0];
}
```

Comment: How did the cells in the range come to be colored the way that they are?  is there some logic to why they are the color they are?

Comment: Hi Matt - I manually manage and mark the cells in the range with a specific color. Over time I want to evaluate which is the smallest value among these values. I also want the "smallest" to be dynamic.

Comment: i figured you were doing it manually, i was just wondering if there was some logic to it?

Answer (score 0):

The color change does not automatically refresh the result. For this, you can add a dummy parameter, like a checkbox for example, and check/uncheck to refresh. Call this parameter by writing for instance

```
=minValColoredCells(___________,___________,$A$1)
```

where A1 contains the checkbox

You have to change a little the script

```
var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\)/).pop().split(',')[0];
```

and

```
var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\)/).pop().split(',')[1];
```

[image]

the complete script will be

```
function minValColoredCells(countRange, colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\)/).pop().split(',')[0];
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\)/).pop().split(',')[1];
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var colourarray = []

  for (var i = 0; i < bg.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < bg[0].length; j++) {
      if (bg[i][j] == color) {
        colourarray.push(values[i][j])
      }
    }
  }

  var smallest = colourarray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return smallest[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike for helping out. I did not change anything in the function. added a checkbox in cell A1 and called the function exactly like you did but I get an error "Range not found". It seems to stumble at line 14 of the custom function code i.e. var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);

Comment: I completed my answer. (In fact for me, I don't use the second parameter which is the colorRef, I prefer to choose the color in the active cell = the cell that contains the function, but here I leave it as it is to avoid any changes major)

Comment: Thanks, Mike. The script works for me now. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Mike. As an extension to my question below, can we also identify the exact cell position of the smallest number identified? That would add a lot of value to what I am doing.

Comment: You can add in E1 this formula `=query({arrayformula(row(A:A)),A:A},"select Col1 where Col2="&D1&" ")` to get the line of the relevant value. Note that you can have multiple lines with the same minimum value.

Comment: I have been using this custom function you helped me with for a few months now and I would like to extend it slightly. Instead of returning the smallest number in the array, I I get the entire array of numbers sorted in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in my opinion.  The real solution here is to manage the details of the colors using a code of some sort rather than manually changing the colors.  Then you're not going to be stuck using AppScript to read colors, you can just use a formula to read text to find the minimum with a MINIFS() based formula.

[Here is a spreadsheet explaining the solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17gHczAgZvWVUiRFRfuMVDMPbukZc7dXTLLl6CpKF524/edit#gid=2100307022).